# glass java starter project on appengine localhost

Tags: google-app-engine, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I created appEngine project from the Maven glass java starter project, and I am trying to run it as appengine:devserver
But, when I try to access the localhost on the browser, it says:-
"This webpage has a redirect loop".

Also, how do I delete the cache on the chrome browser, because even when the localserver is not running, I still get the above mentioned error, unless I delete the cache from the browser and restart my Windows m/c.

Comment: I was able to deploy the starter project on appengine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue. 
Basically, it was a url-rewriting issue and the Jetty server was inserting the sessionId (`jsessionId`) into the URL.
I disabled this by having this in the `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionURL</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and this in the `appengine-web.xml`:

```
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "localhost", try creating a host entry in your   %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file (eg. devserver.example.com 127.0.01)

When testing, you can disable Chrome cache by going into devtools and clicking the settings gear.

Comment: Changing the etc\hosts file as you suggested did not help. Still getting the same error - "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Comment: You'll need to trace the network requests in Chrome devtools to see what the loop is, then trace the code to see where the loop is originating

Comment: for some reasons App Engine does not like this code in the AuthFilter.java httpResponse.sendRedirect(WebUtil.buildUrl(httpRequest, "/oauth2callback"));    This code would redirect to Authorization via Google services.